# Cutting down tiff file layer to smaller polygon using ArcGIS Desktop

Tags: arcgis-desktop, geotiff-tiff, clip, region

I have a dynamic land map featuring open forest, closed forest etc of an area which is a tiff layer file. I want to be able to cut the layer file to my area of interest, the polygon I created.

How do I retrieve data from my dynamic land map just in that polygon region?

Answer (score 3):

In ArcToolbox > Data Management > Raster > Raster Processing > Clip there is a check box to clip it to the shape of your polygon.